# How can I edit the title of a folder or file in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: document-library, file, title

I am looking at some documents on our SharePoint. In the list view, there are somehow two columns, "Title" and "Name".

While "Name" shows the file name (as it appears when synchronizing the content to Explorer), "Title" shows "New Folder" (or the equivalent thereof in German, "Neuer Ordner").

**How can I change that title?**

[image: SharePoint files list]

The built-in help system just appears to tell me how to add or remove columns, not how to fill the *Title* column in particular.

Furthermore, I have clicked the properties icon (on the left, next to the folder icon), but this brings me to a form where I can only change the name, not the title. I am getting to the very same form when clicking the ellipsis button next to the date (`...`), then the ellipsis button in the popup, and then *edit properties*:

[image: Edit Properties form without a way to edit the title]

This is the entire screen while one of the untitled folders is selected:

[image: entire SharePoint screen]

Is there anywhere else where I could click to configure any settings for the selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the Name also changes the Title to the same value.

Select the item and choose "Edit Properties" in the ribbon menu after creation.(Title field isn't filled on creation only after edit)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "ribbon menu", please? I have added a screenshot of the entire SharePoint desktop in my browser to the question, and I see nothing that resembles a ribbon (an enlarged toolbar-like kind of thing with a mess of icons and other controls in different sizes, right?) in there. (Sorry for the stupid questions, I must be missing something very obvious.)

Comment: Ribbon is the menu on top of you screen.  In your screen print you did pressed the "Dateien" Tab? There you can select the "Edit Properties" However it could that it is prohibited?

Comment: Ah. It's one of those modern hidden ribbons that are collapsed by default. I can click "Edit Properties", but it brings me to the form shown above once again, where I can only edit the name, not the title.

Comment: You edit a Folder, as far as I know if you change the name it also changes the title to the same. You tried that already I guess?

Comment: Not yet, because I didn't want to change the name. I'll try ...

Comment: Ok, that did work :) Granted, the title column seems a bit pointless now if it can only ever have the same value as the name column.

Comment: Yeah, weird thing is, when you create a folder it doesn't fill the title, but after edit the name it does.

Comment: Ok, can you add a remark about the title changing along when the name gets changed (and there being no way to change the title independently of the name) to your answer, please? Then I'll accept it (because that's the behaviour I could successfully verify and confirm).

Comment: ...It is done :)